# Getting real world relative pixels per inch in a given image

Tags: image, image-processing, bitmap

This is probably a very simple answer but I want to double check I'm not making some obvious assumption.

Let's say I have a picture of a person...and I know that person is 66 inches tall.  If I want to determine how many pixels represents one inch RELATIVE TO THE IMAGE ITSELF...do I simply divide the number of pixels / the number of inches?

Example:

Person a = 66 inches tall

Bitmap of person a = person a is 500 pixels in the Bitmap

Pixels in "real world" inches of the photo -> 500 / 60??

[image: Stick man]

Comment: Yes, to get pixels per inch you divide the number of pixels by the number of inches ... 500/66

Comment: @Mark Setchell - This answers the question and while the question might seem elementary (I was just double checking) it might indeed help someone if you want to add your response as the answer.  I will accept it.